# finding specific values in text file python

Tags: python, file

[image]

I have a text file that looks like the one above. How do I get python to read the file such that I only obtain the values for 'gps_alt' 'lat' and 'lon'?

Comment: you shouldn't use images of text, just copy paste the text into the question

Comment: It would help tremendously if you would provide the file contents as text instead of an image. That way a person trying to answer your question can easily copy the text so they can play around with it when formulating an answer for you.

Also, you'll need to let us know what format the text file is in. While it appears to be JSON, I can't verify that because you've neither stated such nor provided text.

Comment: ahhh ok sorry still new to stack but it's a file structure not many are aware of it's an IGC file.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see how the text file is structured exactly but it looks like a json file so you could try something like this to store the text file into a dict:

```
import json

with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

then you have a normal python dictionary and can loop through the keys/values and get the ones you need.